# Is it possible to setup SVN server on local and then access it from anywhere?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I want to setup svn server on local, but it should be accessible from anywhere. Currently we can access it within network.
other way, how we can make a system accessible from anywhere with IP? either how to convert it to a server.

Comment: Svn server is a server, you don't need to convert it to a server!  Just ensure that no firewall is blocking connections and you can access it from any machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `svnserve` or `httpd` as the server (and not accessing it via `file://`, you can access it from anywhere in the entire world.

Provided:

1. Your routers aren't blocking the access.
2. Your system isn't blocking that port.

Unfortunately, those can be two very big ifs - especially point #1. If you have Windows and are using `svnserve`, you'll need to set Windows Firewall to unblock port 3690. Other PCs may have to do the same. Once that is done, everyone on your network segment should be able to access your repository on your system. For broader access, you'll have to configure your router, or in a corporate network ask the IT department to open that port on their routers.

And, I would not blame a corporate IT administrator from refusing your request. They'll insist that this has to be put on a server, and not a user machine, and they'll also insist that this should be done via the VPN. They should insist that you have a backup plan and all sorts of other paperwork.

If you don't mind having your code viewable globally, you can put your code on many open source sites that use Subversion as a server. Heck, even Github allows you to access your repository with Subversion.

If your the only one accessing the code, you could put your repository directory on a [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) directory. The main thing is that you can never access this repository from more than one place at a time. Ever.

Comment: You gorgot one more "if": if (in case of Apache) server listens on external IP

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to the server from outside, and svn installed on the server as well, you're good to go! Just use the svn+ssh:// protocol and let the existing user management do the rest.